# Foreign key constraint lead to a duplicate entry in MySQL 5.7 but not 5.6

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I am trying to upgrade the database from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7, so I need to test all queries that I have at the back end in MySQL 5.7. When I try to update a table, an error is reported:

> SQL Error (1761): Foreign key constraint for table 'table 1', record '****' would lead to a duplicate entry in table 'table 2', key 'PRIMARY'

The reason is table 2 has a foreign key referencing a colum in table 1, when any value is updated, then the same value in table 2 is also updated. I know why this error is reported, but I cannot understand why this problem does not happen in MySQL 5.6.

I try to change some values in table 1 in MySQL 5.6, and the database does report this error, however, it is not working when I use **UPDATE** statement to update the table.

I tried to search for the cause of this result but got nothing. Would you please tell me why the result is different in MySQL 5.6 and 5.7?

Comment: I can't think of anything implemented in 5.7 that would cause this issue. Can you share your table DDLs and some sample data and update statement that would recreate this scenario?